# Request "wait" time is high. Do you see any issue with this HTTP2.0 header?

Tags: performance, http, caching, web-applications, http-headers

In my website, only one request,(ie. the root request) is taking more time. Especially the "wait" time is high. The HTTP2.0 Header for the request that is taking more time is posted below. Do you see any issue that might cause this request to take more "wait" time?

I have just removed the domain name. Please post your thoughts. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
cache-control         : max-age=0
cf-cache-status        : DYNAMIC
cf-ray                 : 5a1adf4d010925-SEA
cf-request-id          : c4e5021110925303a9200000001
content-encoding       : br
content-type           : text/html; charset=UTF-8
date                   : Thu, 11 Jun 2020 12:26:39 GMT
expect-ct              : max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires                : Thu, 11 Jun 2020 12:26:37 GMT
host-header            : b7440e60b07ee7b80454eff108fab2118
link                   : <https://www.<domainname>.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://www.<domainname>.com/>; rel=shortlink
server                 : cloudflare
set-cookie             : __cfduid=d775816f66f9fe58d133f15c6546544654078397; expires=Sat, 11-Jul-20 12:26:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.<domainname>.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
status                 :200
vary                   : Accept-Encoding
x-cache-enabled        : False
x-proxy-cache          : MISS
```

Comment: Your response headers don't usually have information about *why* a server is slow to respond.

Comment: It might help to share how slow it is and what you think is a reasonable time

Comment: The only thing of note is that the cache-control has max-age=0 which means this may not be cached, neither in browser nor in your CDN (Cloudflare) - which you can see as x-proxy-cache is set to MISS. So this request always goes all the way back to the origin. What happens at that point and how responsive your origin server is, isn’t apparent from the little information you’ve given.